# How to isolate certain raster values using raster calculator?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, band

I have a one band grayscale image. It has values 0-63 within the band. I need to isolate some of those values. Is there a way to do this in the raster calculator?

QGIS 2.2//Windows 7[image]

Comment: Aaron, thank you. I was actually doing the calculation part properly, but I forgot to go into the new raster file, style, and select load min/max. My original problem was that I did not do this, therefore all I saw was a black image on the screen. Problem solved.

Comment: this is not an answer to your question.  Please either edit your question or add this as a comment to Aaron's answer.  Also, if Aaron's answer solved your problem, please accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the following type of expression:

```
("YOUR_IMAGE@1" > 150) * "YOUR_IMAGE@1"
```

The resulting image of an arid woodland shows only the pixel values > 150 and all other values are displayed as 0 (black).

[image]